# Keep gif animations running angular

Tags: angularjs, gif

I have a question about gif animations.  My current situation is:

I have an angular script. with a heavily model sometimes. This means.. 1000+ records in an array can change in an instance. This is quite a heavy dom manipulation done by angular js too. I also have some gif animations running on the page when that happens. With the dom manipulation comes the problem that gif animations get stuck. The usual solution for that is : put some timeout between the dom manipulation so the animation gets the chance to run.

Now the problem is. That i dont want to put timeouts in my angular controllers. It should never be the task of the controller to keep the page run smoothly. Is there an option in angular to lower the priority of the dom manipulation below the level of the animation running. and if not,what would be the right place in angular to interfere  with the dom manipulation to get the model into the dom?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'what would be the right place in angular to interfere with the dom manipulation to get the model into the dom'?

Comment: Well.. Usually when you want to avoid the browser to get stuck or animations to get stuck, you add some timeouts between the dom manipulations. Thats the only way to avoid it. So if angularjs doesnt have an option to do dom manipulation on lower priority, i will have to interfere with the dom manipulation done by angular. Atleast that was what i was thinking.